# Sharepoint online page in iframe not executing button click code behind from ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, iframe, sharepoint

I am trying to use Sharepoint online to access a private site build in ASP.NET (VB.NET code behind). The page displays, but soon as I click any of the buttons on that page, it shows an error.

I am displaying the ASP.NET app in web part iframe. Is there something I need to enable in Sharepoint online? So that it can execute the button click events on the aspx pages?

Answer (score -1):

If you got an answer to this, I'd be stoked to know what you figured out.  I'm having an issue with some html I'm injecting into SharePoint Online via an iframe pointing to an aspx file.  All was working but suddenly it has stopped.

Comment: Its not an answer, please use for this kind of message the "comment" section